# Audio file not playing in Chrome

Tags: html

I am coding an e-card for fathers day but i have run into some problems- my code for playing audio doesn't make the music play. Any advice on how fix this would be  much appreciated. Here is the code for the music:

```
<audio autoplay loop>
      <source src="Republic - Rád gondoltam.mp3">
</audio>
```

And here is the code for the whole thing.

```
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Happy Father's Day</title>
            <style>               
                img {
                    margin: 0;
                    position: absolute;
                    top: 50%;
                    left: 50%
                    margin-right: -50%;
                    transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
                    }
            </style>
        </head>
        <body>
<audio autoplay loop>
      <source src="Republic - Rád gondoltam.mp3">
</audio>
            <center>
                <img src="output_tzHVLY.gif" />
            </center>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Is the file definitely in the same directory as the html file?

Comment: @DarrenSweeney yh it is, i was forgetting to specify the file type: type="audio/mpeg"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the file type:

```
<audio autoplay loop>
      <source src="Republic - Rád gondoltam.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

Also, I would check for the exact name of the file - "Republic - Rád gondoltam.mp3" seems to be a not-so-good filename (includes spaces and special charcter á) - maybe change the filename to something like "republic_rad_gondoltam.mp3"

Comment: thank you so much it works now, really appreciate it. :]

Comment: @PokeSteelProductions see my answer for firefox support